# Multiprocessing under Jenkins VM hangs

Tags: python, linux, python-2.7, jenkins, python-multiprocessing

```
   def multi_run_wrapper(self, args):
       return self.parrallel(*args)


    try:
        pool = multiprocessing.Pool(maxtasksperchild=1)
        chunksize, extra = divmod(len(dictionary), cpu_count() * 4)
        if extra:
            chunksize += 1
        results = pool.imap_unordered(self.multi_run_wrapper, dictionary.iteritems(), chunksize)
    except Exception as ex:
        print "Error in pool", str(ex)
    finally:
        pool.close()
        pool.join()
```

I am using `multiprocessing` for faster execution.The base function does a `request.get` and `request.post` on different urls based on inputs to function.This runs fine on my mac but when run on linux vm through jenkins it hangs.I have tried all options like `map,imap,map_async` .I am using `pandas` so i also tried to check `cpu_affinity` but its correctly set to `16` in my case.I also tried without `maxtasksperchild`.I have exhausted all options now.Is there something else i can try ?

P.S : on jenkins when the process hangs...when i terminate through jenkins,it still remains in `ps - ef | grep python` the same script which i had run.

After running `gdb` i can see 3 processes waiting.There seems to be a deadlock!!!!

Thread info when hung

```
info threads
  Id   Target Id         Frame 
  4    Thread 0x7f4172227700 (LWP 6623) 0x00007f41e1a595e3 in select ()
at ../sysdeps/unix/syscall-template.S:82
  3    Thread 0x7f4171826700 (LWP 6624) 0x00007f41e23a56fd in write () at ../sysdeps/unix/syscall-template.S:82
  2    Thread 0x7f41d1186700 (LWP 6625) 0x00007f41e23a575d in read () at ../sysdeps/unix/syscall-template.S:82
* 1    Thread 0x7f41e27c5700 (LWP 6196) sem_wait () at ../nptl/sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/x86_64/sem_wait.S:86

Thread 4 (Thread 0x7f4172227700 (LWP 6623)):
Traceback (most recent call first):
  (frame information optimized out)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/threading.py", line 763, in run
self.__target(*self.__args, **self.__kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/threading.py", line 810, in __bootstrap_inner
    self.run()
(frame information optimized out)

Thread 3 (Thread 0x7f4171826700 (LWP 6624)):
Traceback (most recent call first):
(frame information optimized out)
   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/threading.py", line 763, in run
self.__target(*self.__args, **self.__kwargs)
   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/threading.py", line 810, in __bootstrap_inner
    self.run()
(frame information optimized out)

Thread 2 (Thread 0x7f41d1186700 (LWP 6625)):
Traceback (most recent call first):
(frame information optimized out)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/threading.py", line 763, in run
self.__target(*self.__args, **self.__kwargs)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/threading.py", line 810, in __bootstrap_inner
self.run()
(frame information optimized out)

Thread 1 (Thread 0x7f41e27c5700 (LWP 6196)):
Traceback (most recent call first):
Waiting for the GIL
(frame information optimized out)
(frame information optimized out)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/multiprocessing/pool.py", line 457, in join
self._worker_handler.join()
 File "/home/jenkins/fsroot/workspace/testvivekpds/utils/r_p/RRFP.py", line 942, in u_r_t_p
pool.join()
(frame information optimized out)
(frame information optimized out)
```

Comment: How many memory have you defined for Jenkins VM (-Xmx and -Xms, -Xss for stack size)?

Comment: @RaphaelMoita the linux vm has 16 gb ram,16 cpu's

Comment: Sorry, I meant JVM. Jenkins is running over an Application Server that has its own JVM memory configuration. Maybe Jenkins is hanging because your process is overloading this specific point.

Comment: @RaphaelMoita how can i check that

Comment: Look for jenkins.xml. Somewhere in this file there will be a tag <arguments>. Inside that, probably, you gonna find the JVM arguments like -Xmx

Comment: Try using `map` instead of `imap_unordered`. You need to consume the result objects and as a bonus you'll see if there were any exceptions raised in the workers. As a minimum, `result = list(pool.imap_unordered(...))`.

Comment: I encountered something similar with python multiprocessing under jenkins.
It occasionally hangs even when using map. Did you eventually resolve this issue?

Comment: @odedfos i could not solve this...so used Gevents instead of multiprocessing and it solved my use case